# How can I disable a navigation bar button when input on a ViewController is invalid?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller, let's call it AddAlarmViewController.swift, which is inside a navigation controller, and in which I call

`prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

This AddAlarmViewController comprises a screen in my iOS application that creates a new Alarm to add to a stack of Alarms back in a separate UIViewController based on input from some DatePickers.

Inside this `prepare` method, essentially before I return from this AddAlarmViewController to AlarmTableViewController, I use the following code

```
    // Configure the destination view controller only when the save button is pressed.
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("The cancel button was pressed, cancelling from AddAlarmViewController", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }
```

After this, I pull the times from each datePicker into variables and use those variables to build an Alarm object.

The problem is that all of my logic for deciding whether a time is valid or not (end time is before start time, etc.) is contained in the Alarm object's init method and not in this AddAlarmViewController, so I can't seem to figure out how to change the navigation bar save button item to be disabled while invalid times are entered. Do I need to make the AddAlarmViewController a Delegate for the Alarm class or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is put the logic into

```
  func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier, sender: Any?) -> Bool
```

That may help you solve the issue.

```
 extension : UIViewController{
 override  func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier:    NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier, sender: Any?) -> Bool{
return true
```

}
}

Comment: This doesn't explain what file to put this method into, nor how it works :(. The Apple documentation on this method is dreadfully short.

Comment: You are suppose to override shouldPerformSegue in your presenting UIViewController or add an extension for all UIViewControllers. BTW, there are tons of examples here. Just search via SO.

Comment: I guess what I'm confused about is how does the data from inside my Alarm object get back to my AddAlarmViewController? How does shouldPerformSeque() help me with that?